# File delete should be leaving 7 days of files but is only leaving 5...why?

Tags: powershell

My company had an old batch script that ran every 15 minutes and collected the event log from two servers and put it in a location where devs can access it for triage purposes.

It created and then maintained an event log file (.evtx) for each server for an entire day and then started a new one the next day, etc.

I recently re-wrote it from batch to powershell and added some folder cleanup, file zipping, etc. but that is only partially working.

**Issue:**

Script should be checking for the last 7 files, based on creation date and ignoring them. It should remove anything that is in the 8th, 9th, 10th, etc. spot. Instead it is only leaving 5 files in one folder (for one server) and 4 files in another folder (for another server). I don't know why. Another issue I've noticed once or twice is that it'll delete a file that is in the 4th spot of the list but ignore the 5th and then delete the 6th, etc.

I'm not sure about the zips part which is set to 60 days as my script has only been running for about 20-25 days.

**Code:**

```
# Cleaning up LogFile folder

Write-Output "Cleaning up existing *.evtx, *.zip and *.7z files to ensure efficient disk space usage..." | Out-File $HistFile -append
Write-Output " " | Out-File $HistFile -append

# Now cleaning up event logs at an interval of 7 days

$EventLogsCount = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Exclude *.zip, *.7z, *.ps1, *.txt  | Where {-not $_.PsIsContainer} | Sort CreationTime -desc | Select -Skip 7 | %{$_.Count}

if ($EventLogsCount -eq $null)
{
    Write-Output "No event logs to remove..." | Out-File $HistFile -append
    Write-Output " " | Out-File $HistFile -append
}
else
{
     Write-Output "Removing the following event log files:" | Out-File $HistFile -append
     Write-Output " " | Out-File $HistFile -append
     Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Exclude *.zip, *.7z, *.ps1, *.txt  | Where {-not $_.PsIsContainer} | Sort CreationTime -desc | Select -Skip 7 | foreach {
     $_ | Remove-Item -Recurse
        if (Test-Path $_)
        {
            "Failed to remove $_"
        }
        else
        {
            "$_"
        }
    } | Out-File $HistFile -append
    Write-Output " " | Out-File $HistFile -append
}

# Cleaning up zips at a greater interval of 60 days

$ZipsCount = Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Exclude *.evtx, *.ps1, *.txt | Where {-not $_.PsIsContainer} | Sort CreationTime -desc | Select -Skip 60 | %{$_.Count}

if ($ZipsCount -eq $null)
{
    Write-Output "No zipped files to remove..." | Out-File $HistFile -append
}
else
{
    Write-Output "Removing the following zipped files:" | Out-File $HistFile -append
    Write-Output " " | Out-File $HistFile -append
    Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Exclude *.evtx, *.ps1, *.txt | Where {-not $_.PsIsContainer} | Sort CreationTime -desc | Select -Skip 60 | foreach {
    $_ | Remove-Item -Recurse
        if (Test-Path $_)
        {
            "Failed to remove $_"
        }
        else
        {
            "$_"
        }
    } | Out-File $HistFile -append
    Write-Output " " | Out-File $HistFile -append
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is a little wonky. Currently, you're gathering a list of files and skipping x number of them as a whole based on their sorted creation time.  You can use `Get-ChildItem`'s `-Include` flag instead of excluding everything else.  I've rewritten the script to be more easily read and functional.  It looks at the file's last written time and filters based on your threshold (7 days for event logs, or 60 days for zip files)

---

Script rewritten for intended functionality:

```
# Log script functionality
"Cleaning up existing *.evtx, *.zip and *.7z files to ensure efficient disk space usage...`r`n" >> $HistFile

# Now cleaning up event logs at an interval of 7 days
$EventLogs = GCI $Path -Include *.evtx -Recurse |
               ? { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) }

If (!$EventLogs) {
    "No event logs to remove...`r`n" >> $HistFile
} Else {
    "Removing the following event log files:`r`n" >> $HistFile
    $EventLogs |
        % {
            Try {
              Remove-Item $_ -EA Stop
              $_.FullName >> $HistFile
            } Catch {
              "Failed to remove $($_.FullName)" >> $HistFile
            }
        }
}

# Cleaning up zips at a greater interval of 60 days
$ZipFiles = GCI $Path -Include *.zip,*.7z -Recurse |
              ? { $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60) }
If (!$ZipFiles) {
    "No zipped files to remove..." >> $HistFile
} Else {
    "Removing the following zipped files:`r`n" >> $HistFile
    $ZipFiles |
        % {
            Try {
              Remove-Item $_ -EA Stop
              $_.FullName >> $HistFile
            } Catch {
              "Failed to remove $($_.FullName)" >> $HistFile
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @TheIncorrigible1. I'm still learning PS (self-taught) so always nice 
to learn other ways to do something. I will tweak mine and report back (possibly tomorrow as work is hot and heavy today). Much appreciated.

Comment: So, @TheIncorrigible1, your script ends up working although having it set to -7 for some reason leaves an extra file so I'm left with 8 each day...no big deal, I can just change it to -6 and have 7...

Never thought of using lastwritetime vs creationtime so I appreciate that tip.